# When is the Jacobian determinant positive

Tags: calculus, jacobian

Suppose we have $F(u, v) = (x, y)$.

The Jacobian of this mapping is denoted by $\dfrac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}$.

Is the Jacobian a positive real number when I evaluate at point $(u, v)$?

I calculate Jacobian using $ \dfrac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} = \det \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{bmatrix} = \det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 1 - 0=1$.

Seems like the Jacobian determinant is always a positive real number under this mapping.

I don't know if I am doing the right thing.

Comment: Why is $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = 1$?

Comment: @DanielApsley I realized I made a mistake. It should be 0. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Also, the sign of the determinant is essentially the orientation of the map. The determinant is supposed to measure the effect on area and the orientation of the function. For example, $f(x,y) = (y,x)$ has jacoian $-1$ . It also transforms the $1 \times 1$ square(ie. $[0,1] \times [0,1]$) to itself with the opposite orientation.

Comment: Usually the word "Jacobian" refers to the *Jacobian matrix*. Here you mean the Jacobian determinant. I recommend to edit your question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The Jacobian is not a real number. For a map between $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ it is at each point where it is evaluated a matrix. In your case a square matrix of dimension$2$.

And the determinant of the Jacobian is a real number. Not a positive one in general.

For your specific map, the determinant is equal to $1$.

Comment: People sometimes use [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) to refer to the determinant (as well as the matrix).

Comment: @angryavian Being French, I don’t have enough practice to judge that. That is not easing if two different things are denoted by the same word!

Comment: @mathcounterexample.net Why does the determinant equal to 1? I edited my post. I think it should be 0.

Comment: @Vito Your work before your edit was fine; you just needed to note that the off-diagonal entries $\partial u / \partial v$ and $\partial v / \partial u$ are zero.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I totally agree that it is unfortunate that a term refers to two separate notions, mais c'est la vie

Comment: @angryavian I have another question. I believe Jacobian is the factor of distortion of a small rectangular area. Why can the Jacobian be negative? The area cannot be negative.

Comment: @Vito The Jacobian also incorporates orientation of the distortion. If one of the components gets "reversed", the sign of the Jacobian gets negated. (If it helps, think about the one-dimensional case $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where the Jacobian is just the usual derivative, and think about how slopes can be negative.) The absolute value of the Jacobian is the area of the small rectangle after the transformation.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net -  It seems that the English and French usages are the same. [Fr.Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_jacobienne#D%C3%A9terminant_jacobien) says: Si $m = n$, alors la matrice jacobienne de $F$ est une matrice carrée. Son déterminant $\det J_F$ est appelé le *déterminant jacobien*, ou *jacobien*.  Dire que le jacobien est non nul revient donc à dire que la matrice jacobienne est inversible.

Comment: @Henry In fact in French (and that is what French Wikipedia mentions) we speak of the *matrice jacobienne* (2 words)  to denote the matrix. And of the *jacobien* (only one word) to denote the determinant of the *matrice jacobienne*.

Answer (score 3):

The Jacobian determinant $|J|$ at some point $P$ is positive if the orientation at that point is preserved by the map. Further, a negative Jacobian determinant at some point implies that orientation is reversed there.